# Function implicitly calling another function contract

Tags: php

Is there a way for PHP or a "practice" for functions that automatically call another function, or functions that are related and if one is called, the other one is always called after? For example, say we have:

```
function upload() //Upload a song
function publish() //Publishes the recorded song
```

Instead of always adding a `$this->publish()` call at the end of `upload()`, is there a "contract" that can be specified or a practice that makes it evident that `upload` should always be followed by a `publish` (i.e. upon execution, `upload()` can automatically call `publish()`, or some practice for doing this?

Comment: Write a new function and put both function calls into it. So if you call the new defined function, both functions get called

Comment: In procedural approach?

Comment: No, there is not. I'd be confused to backtrack it if there was.

Comment: Sure, it's just plain old function composition. if publish must always be called on upload, add a call to publish in upload.

Comment: if you're always calling publish at the end of upload, what kind of answer do you expect would be simpler than just calling it? really though, you should be using a class. the syntax for combining related functions *is* using classes. if you were using a class, you could use the `__call()` magic method to do that, but still wouldn't be simpler than just calling the method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there is no official syntax for related functions.

You could add an argument to upload to automatically publish it:

```
function upload($formkey, $autopublish = true) {
    // something here
    if($autopublish) {
       publish();
    }
}
```

Or you could write a class that would parse annotations in documentation blocks to check if any other functions have to be executed.

Comment: well there is an official syntax, even has it's own acronym, OOP :p